# Is it bad to wrap entire html document in <form>?

Tags: html, forms

I have a database front-end that has several text fields for input on top of the page using post, and a pagination bar at the bottom of the page that uses the post method as well.

I've encapsulated the top inputs in

```
<form method = 'post'>

<Body>

 //Inputs

//Table contents


//Pagination bar buttons

</Body>


</Form>
```

, but I've also extended the form so the form extends to the bottom of the document. (Database table is returned in middle of document) If I start a new form tag, the request will not include the previously entered text fields on the top, only the input inside the bottom form, so I can't use two forms.

```
<Html>
<Form method ='post'>

//Inputs 
</Form>
//Table results

<Form method = 'post'>
//Pagination bar buttons
</Form> 
</Html>
```

This will not work.
 I want to ask, is it ok to encapsulate entire html doc in form tag? I don't want the client to send the entire doc in post or something.

Comment: `form` elements can contain many child elements, there's no technical reason why they shouldn't.  Whether or not your design is *ideal* we can't really know given the information here.

Comment: What you're describing is basically how the ASP.NET 1-2x PostBack mechanism worked: two-way input controls must exist in a single `<form>` element. It wasn't pretty.

Comment: Have you thought about duplicating the other inputs as `<hidden />` inputs inside your main form? You can also re-populate those fields when the response HTML is generated in for a POST request.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean this, that's fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>This is OK</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        Everything
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

But

```
<form>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Yes this is bad</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Something
    </body>
    </html>
</form>
```

or

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<form>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Yes this is bad</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Something
    </body>
    </html>
</form>
```

Is just invalid.

Comment: Can you explain why it's invalid? I'm currently using the example at the bottom and it's working fine

Comment: This is what I gather from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/html. Being the _root_ element, there can't be more than one in a document. It is possible that your browser is correcting this as an attempt to display something. Look at the rendered DOM in the inspector and that should clarify if that's the case.

Comment: *I'm currently using the example at the bottom* @user4757174 - That information should be in the question itself. You've currently got two answers where people are guessing what you mean by *encapsulate entire html doc in form tag*.

Comment: Yes, please, @user4757174 update your question to clarify what you are after, with before and after code examples if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing(s) that will be submitted in a form are values associated with input tags.  So the entire document won't be submitted in the form.  Only values associated with inputs.
Whether or not your design is "a bad idea" is hard to tell with the information given.  I am unable to tell why exactly your pagination bar needs to be a form at all (rather than a link) but again, if you're worried about the entire document submitting in the form, that won't happen.

Comment: Pagination bar is a button instead of a link because the method is post (can't put variable in URL using post)